# How can I solve this OpenSSL "EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt" error in PHP?

Tags: php, encryption, openssl

Setup:

```
session_start();

function set_encryption_method() {

if (isset($_SESSION['last_activity']) && (time() - $_SESSION['last_activity']) > 3600) {
    unset($_SESSION['cipher']);
    unset($_SESSION['iv']);
    unset($_SESSION['last_activity']);
}

$cipher = 'aes-256-cbc';
$iv = random_bytes(16);    
    
    if (in_array($cipher, openssl_get_cipher_methods())) {
        if (!isset($_SESSION['cipher'])) {
            $_SESSION['cipher'] = $cipher;
        }
        if (!isset($_SESSION['iv'])) {
            $_SESSION['iv'] = $iv;
        }
        $_SESSION['last_activity'] = time();
    } else {
        die('Encryption method not supported!');
    }
}

set_encryption_method();
```

Encrypt:

```
function encrypt_string($key, $string) {
    // $key is a constant stored in a database
    return rawurlencode(base64_encode(openssl_encrypt($string, $_SESSION['cipher'], $key, 0, $_SESSION['iv'])));
}
```

Decrypt:

```
function decrypt_string($key, $encrypted) {
    // $key is a constant stored in a database
    return openssl_decrypt(rawurldecode(base64_decode($encrypted)), $_SESSION['cipher'], $key, 0, $_SESSION['iv']);
}
```

When `decrypt_string()` is called with the appropriate parameters, it throws this error: `digital envelope routines evp_decrypt_final_ex: bad decrypt`.  If I hardcode the iv, then it works correctly.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why don't you **debug** the inputs to "openssl_encrypt" and "openssl_decrypt" and then "follow the data" to find out where the IV get's changed ?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have control over the server and the company will not allow something like XDebug to be installed

Comment: Echo base64_Encode and strlen of the iv. Strlen confirms it's set, base64_encode confirms they are both the same.

Comment: Can you give more info about your environment? I [cannot reproduce](https://paiza.io/projects/BJ2q9TOpEFhFltNgR5KFRg).

Comment: @JohnConde - RHEL 7 x64, httpd24-1.1-19, PHP 7.2.24, OpenSSL 1.0.2k-21

Comment: Normally, you would store the encrypted data and the IV together, since the decryption only works if both of those are kept constant. Can you confirm that you are using the same IV for encryption and decryption? Are you not, by any chance, invoking the encrypt and decrypt functions in two different sessions? Or invoking `set_encryption_method()` in between the two, while more than an hour has passed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message is (indirectly) caused by the fact that your are using different IVs for encryption and decryption. From your description it is not clear how that can happen, but let me propose some suggestions that will avoid your issue altogether.

First, with EAS-CBC it is not a good idea to use the same IV + key combination multiple times. You can find some discussion on that in the answers to [Is AES in CBC mode secure if a known and/or fixed IV is used?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/5094/is-aes-in-cbc-mode-secure-if-a-known-and-or-fixed-iv-is-used). You did not mention how you are using the different functions, but during 3600 seconds, you are using the same IV + key combinations.

To work around this, you could generate a random IV for every encryption that you do. You could then store the IV together with the encrypted data; the IV is not required or supposed to be secret. The following two functions are modifications of yours that do exactly that, by concatenating the two after encryption and splitting the two before decryption:

```
function encrypt_string($key, $string) {
    // $key is a constant stored in a database
    $iv = random_bytes(16);
    $ciphtxt = openssl_encrypt($string, $_SESSION['cipher'], $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
    return base64_encode($iv.$ciphtxt);
}

function decrypt_string($key, $encrypted) {
    // $key is a constant stored in a database
    $combo = base64_decode($encrypted);
    $iv = substr($combo, 0, 16);
    $ciphtxt= substr($combo, 16);
    return openssl_decrypt($ciphtxt, $_SESSION['cipher'], $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
}
```

Note the use of the flag `OPENSSL_RAW_DATA`. As [the documentation for openssl_encrypt](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-encrypt.php) mentions (not too clearly), the result will be base64-ed if you do not give that flag. You were doing the base64-ing yourself so I added the flag. This also makes it a little easier to handle the (de-)concatenation of the IV and the ciphertext.

---

A few words about the occurrence of that `bad decrypt` error: that is emitted when the padding bytes are different than expected. Since you were using an incorrect IV for decryption, the AES decryption did not result in the original data, with a high probability that the padding bytes therefore did not have the right value.

Answer (score 1):

First point to address: Why are you using URL encode/decode?

Those are for passing parameters through browsers; and the browser generally does the decoding for you so as a base rule - if you've written "urldecode" in your PHP, you've probably gone wrong as you're possibly decoding something already decoded. (Or are not using in the right place, or using when unnecessary)

However, Base64 is (or should be) url-safe, so I'd suggest knocking out the urlencode/decode and see what happens.

---

Second point to address: you need to undo the urlencode/base64 conversion in the reverse order you set.

So `rawurlencode(base64_encode(openssl_encrypt(` reversed is `openssl_decrypt(base64_encode(rawurldecode` (you have the base64 and url decode flipped). But knocking out the urlencode/decode entirely (unless you're adamant you need it) will rectify this too.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I removed ```rawurlencode``` and ```rawurldecode``` but I'm still receiving the same ```bad decrypt``` error.